# How to return to a specified control when cancelling the form.unload event?

Tags: ms-access

I open the form with:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
```

Forms Unload event:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

If Len(Me.acntName.Value) = 0 Then
    Msgbox "Account Name must be specified."      
    Cancel = True
    Me.acntName.SetFocus
end if

End Sub
```

This returns me to the form, but does not give focus to the control.  How do I do this?

Comment: Code works for me. Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: If this is a bound form, checks like this are better placed in `Form_BeforeUpdate`.